# Laravel fetch data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

By using the following code on my controller page, I am trying to fetch data from mysql database.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class productscontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $Products = DB::table('products_description')->get();
        return view('products.index',compact($Products));
    }   
}
```

and receiving the following error.

```
FatalErrorException in productscontroller.php line 12:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found
```

I am following a laracast tutorial to fetch the data but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put `use DB;` or `$Products = \DB::table('products_description')->get();`

Comment: with $Products = \DB::table('products_description')->get(); it is giving the following error PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Comment: Edit your .env file .. Provide database, username and password there

Comment: By using use DB; it is giving the following error syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Comment: I already configured "config > database.php". where should I find .env file you are talking about?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I have tried use DB; on three different places one by one. Under use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; Than in index function and then use DB::table('products_description')->get(); but none worked.

Comment: Put it in line before starting of class

Comment: laravel version 5.2, downloaded and installed 4 days ago

Comment: .env will be present in root folder.

Comment: used like the following but didn't work. use DB;
class productscontroller extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  
  $Products = DB::table('products_description')->get();
  return view('products.index',compact($Products));
 } 
}

Comment: edited .env file and using the following code on index file   @foreach($Products as $Product)
   <div>{{ $Product->products_name }}</div>
  @endforeach
and the error is Undefined variable: Products but I am sending this variable to the index file in the code above

Comment: I think you are facing many issues. I cannot help you with current code. Post the new problem as separate question

Comment: If your DB problem is solved, then other issues should be posted as new question

Comment: I found the problem. I was using $ sign in compact($Products) but it should be compact('Products'). and the problem fixed. @curious_coder. Thanks for your help :) Your initial answer is selected as a final and correct solution.

Comment: No problem. It happens